# ubuntu 20.04 stuck on started gnome display manager

Tags: boot, gnome, 20.04

so my `Ubuntu 20.04 "focal-fossa"` was working fine, but since last two days  whenever i boot my `system`, its keep giving me this error : **Started GNOME Display Manager**, instead of giving me the boot screen Here's the full screen image:

[image]

How can i solve this problem.